# Is the Infini-Lift Lightspeed worth it?

Tags: tiny-tower

In *Tiny Tower* (iOS), is the Infini-Lift Lightspeed worthwhile?  It's fairly expensive at 499 Bux.  Does it have any special features or is it just faster?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a word: **Yes**

It is so incredibly fast. Even better, it's much easier to actually stop at the target floor (even if it's floor 2). For some reason, it's also easier to read the floor numbers.
(Personally, I also think it looks better than the previous elevator, but that might just be me.)

It does take a while to save up for it, but I would definitely recommend it.

Comment: Just got it.  Wow it's fast!

Comment: I'm still saving up, but my wife got hers, and I'd say the stopping distance improvement is actually *more* important than the raw speed. You'll get there faster, *and* stop right where you wanted to be.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely. I actually would recommend not even getting the gold elevator until you have enough bucks to upgrade to the infini-lift lightspeed right away, because the gold elevator has such a frustrating stopping distance.